# Get onclick function working with pointer-events none

Tags: onclick, pointer-events

I need to get function onclick working with pointer-events:none. SO basically when my div is clicked I could get let's say alert, but it would be able to click through that div.

I can't find any solution for this. Maybe any of you know how to bypass it?

Thank you and happy holidays!

Comment: Maybe there are some other ways without pointer-events to let div click through, but record that click?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by "click through"? An example of HTML and Javascript of what you're trying to achieve would be useful...

Comment: @kkara here's the example with almost what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/nqTnz/16/